# TLsharp CHANNELS_TOO_MUCH Exception

Tags: c#, api, telegram

I have been using [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) library for a week but recently I am encountering the Exception:

**CHANNELS_TOO_MUCH**

My code can't get pass the `await client.connect()` function even. I haven't found any documentation on the GitHub repository of the library that describes why this exception occurs. I seems it's not a Exception that occurs because of telegram limitation because it gives me this exception at `connect` function.

Here is my code:

```
public static async Task<TelegramClient> connectTelegram()
{
    store = new FileSessionStore();
    client = new TelegramClient(store, numberToAuthenticate, apiId, apiHash);
    try
    {
        await client.Connect();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Invalid Operation Exception");
        if (e.Message.Contains("Couldn't read the packet length"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Couldn't read the packet length");
            Debug.WriteLine("Retying to Connect ...");
        }
        await connectTelegram();
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("IO Exception while Connecting");
        Debug.WriteLine("Retrying to Connect ...");
        await connectTelegram();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message):
    }
    return client;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is not documented yet. I encountered this exception when I tried to use the same session file for connecting to telegram and calling requests. It seems when a session file is used by different and multiple clients the session file becomes corrupted. All you have to do is deleting the session file and recreate it as you have created it before.

Here is an example of doing that:

```
FileSessionStore store;
TelegramClient client;
store = new FileSessionStore();
client = new TelegramClient(store, numberToAuthenticate, apiId, apiHash);
await client.Connect();
```